# Reset a running sum based on condition within the same partition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, partitioning, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a column for the running sum of a boolean column within a partition of every user ordered by date.

I need the running total to reset to 1 every time the boolean column switches from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 ordered by date. Basically reset at every transition point within the same partition.

Here is a sample of what my proposed data would look like for one user.

| user_id | date | status | desired output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2023-01-31 | 0 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2023-02-28 | 0 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2023-03-31 | 1 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-04-30 | 1 | 2 |
| 1234 | 2023-05-31 | 1 | 3 |
| 1234 | 2023-06-30 | 1 | 4 |
| 1234 | 2023-07-31 | 0 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2023-08-31 | 1 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2023-09-30 | 1 | 2 |

I've tried the following snippet and many variations but it repeats 1 and doesn't do a running sum.

```
SELECT *
, SUM(reset_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_sum
                    FROM (
                      SELECT *
                             , CASE
                                WHEN status_change = 1 THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                             END AS reset_sum
                      FROM (
                        SELECT *
                               , CASE
                                  WHEN LAG(status) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) <> status THEN 1
                                  ELSE 0
                               END AS status_change
                        FROM table1
                      ) subquery1
                    ) subquery2
                    ORDER BY user_id, date
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a gaps-islands type problem.

My preferred solution is to use `lag` (or `lead`) to identify when the status changes, followed by a cumulative sum on this which provides a unique group for each changed section.

With this group to also partition by you can then create your desired cumulative sum:

```
with c as (
  select *, 
    case when 
      status != Lag(status) over(partition by user_id order by date) then 1 
    end changed
  from t
), g as (
  select *, Sum(changed) over(partition by user_id order by date) grp
  from c
)
select user_id, date, status, 
  Sum(status) over(partition by user_id, grp order by date) 
from g;
```

Comment: Thanks Stu! This is exactly the solution I was looking for. Good to know I was in the right vicinity with the use of LAG or LEAD.